# Make a SCNNode drop using gravity?

Tags: ios, scenekit

I have a SceneKit setup and have one Sphere in it that is setup as a Dynamic body.

I am able to run the app and see the sphere drop on the static body floor.

What I am trying to do is setup the scene so the sfere initially does not drop.

Then when a function is run I want the sfere to drop.

what is the correct logic / steps to make the scene suddenly (maybe when a button is pressed or something) drop the sphere?

I have tried also to set the sphere to mass 0 and then set the mass to 100 but it does not cause the drop...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Mass doesn't control how fast something falls.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo%27s_Leaning_Tower_of_Pisa_experiment) This is true in the real world, but more so in simulations that take shortcuts instead of simulating every detail of real-world physics. (Sadly, iOS devices still don't have the CPU power to account for the rotating reference frame of the Earth, the Van der Waals attraction between your sphere and any body especially close to it, the strong force that keeps its <strike>triangles</strike> atoms together, etc etc.) In SceneKit, gravity is just a constant acceleration in a specific direction.

Setting mass to zero and switching it to something else interferes with the distinction between static/kinematic and dynamic bodies... so don't do that.

[As @mnuages notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27846902/957768), you can add/remove the physics body from your sphere when you want it to be affected or unaffected by physics entirely.

But what if you want to keep the sphere's physics body for other reasons—such as allowing other bodies to collide with it even before you make it start falling? There are a few approaches you could use for that:

- Set the sphere body's [`damping`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNPhysicsBody_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNPhysicsBody/damping) to 1.0.
- Set the sphere body's [`velocityFactor`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNPhysicsBody_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNPhysicsBody/velocityFactor) to zero (at least in the direction of gravity).

Both of those will keep the sphere from moving when something else hits it. If you want the ball to get knocked around, but not be affected by gravity, the best thing to do might be to switch out scene gravity for physics fields:

1. Set `scene.physicsWorld.gravity` to `SCNVector3Zero`.
2. Add a `SCNPhysicsField` created with the [`linearGravityField`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNPhysicsField_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SCNPhysicsField/linearGravityField) constructor to your scene, and set its `direction` and `strength` to get the kind of gravity behavior you want.
3. Set the `categoryBitMask`s on both your sphere body and the gravity field such that the field affects other bodies but not the sphere.

Whichever of these methods you use, you can change them when you want to ["turn gravity on"](http://media-cache-ec0.pinimg.com/736x/11/e7/47/11e7477bca0879cafeb4be053767b2a4.jpg) for the sphere: reduce the `damping`, reset the `velocityFactor`, or change the sphere's or the gravity field's `categoryBitMask`.

Comment: your explanation was really well done. So this is what I ended up doing: in setting up the node I did this "myNode.velocityFactor = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0)" and this "myNode.damping = 1.0". Then at a certain event trigger I set those to: "myNode.physicsBody?.velocityFactor = SCNVector3Make(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)" and "myNode.physicsBody?.damping = 0.8". That made it so the node would drop like I wanted. Thank you

Comment: You shouldn't need both damping and velocity factor — either alone should do it.

Comment: I tried to only use damping without setting any velocityFactor and it didn't work meaning that the nodes would still fall slowly actually (really slowly but still fall). So I tried both and it worked.

Comment: Velocity factor scales *all* motion from the physics simulation, so if it's zero a body won't move at all, regardless of damping.

Comment: You are correct. So I just tried to only use the velocityFactor approach without messing with Damping and it works. So what I see here is only using Damping does not do what I need but only using velocityFactor does.

Comment: There is one thing that I wish this solution would be better at. I implemented a scene that has hundreds of nodes that need to "drop" when an event is triggered. That means I am looping through each node and setting the velocityFactor on each before they can drop, there is a lag... is there a better way to accomplish this and make it so I don't have to loop through all of them? Is there a way to simply change the setting of the scene itself which would then apply to any node that was already crated with the proper setting to react to gravity?

Comment: Note the field based option in my answer. If you get that set up, all you have to do to start/stop all the nodes dropping is change the field's category.

Comment: As of iOS 9, you can use the `isAffectedByGravity` property on the sphere's physics body for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 4):

As of iOS 9, you can set the `isAffectedByGravity` property to `false` then flip the value to `true` to make the sphere drop: https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnphysicsbody/1514738-isaffectedbygravity

Answer (score 1):

setting a physics body to sphere only when you want to it to be affected by gravity should work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: it does. If you want an object to drop because of gravity you set it a physics body and you're done. If you don't want it to fall anymore, removing its physics body is the most efficient way to go.

Comment: As of iOS 9, you can use the `isAffectedByGravity` property on the sphere's physics body for a simpler solution ... but you already knew that @mnuages :)